# Mage 2 Refused to execute script from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: magento2

I am learning Magento2. I installed it but an error occurs while I fire url on browser. I installed Magento on Windows 7 using xampp server but I receive errors like:

1. Refused to execute script from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
2. Uncaught Error: Script error for: js/theme
3. requirejs.config is not functioning.

Please help me if you have a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have install successfully , you need to deploy static content.
Run the following command from you project directory.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue on an Adobe Commerce Cloud project. Following below steps helped me to resolve the issue Refused to apply style from 'URL' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75515553/9185662